# php object access from json

Tags: php, json

I have a json reply from an api and i want some data.

the response looks like this:

```
{
 "user_id": null,
 "flight_info": {
      "YU24268": {
    "seat": {
      "width": 45.72,
      "pitch": 73.66
    },
    "delay": {
      "ontime_percent": 0.66666669,
      "max": 53,
      "mean": 37,
      "min": 28
    }
  },
   "delay": {
      "ontime_percent": 0.67741936,
      "max": 305,
      "mean": 33,
      "min": 0
    }
  }
},
"travelpayouts_api_request": true,
"clean_marker": "75089",
"currency": "usd",
"internal": false,
"airports": {
  "ORY": {
    "rates": "12",
    "city_code": "PAR",
    "country_code": "FR",
    "country": "France",
    "time_zone": "Europe/Paris",
    "name": "Paris Orly Airport",
    "city": "Paris"
  },
  "SXF": {
    "rates": "27",
    "city_code": "BER",
    "country_code": "DE",
    "country": "Germany",
    "time_zone": "Europe/Berlin",
    "name": "Schonefeld Airport",
    "city": "Berlin"
  }
}
```

I use this code to find the airport i need (from the IATA code), but i can not get the city.

```
function find_city_from_IATA($my_value, $key1)
{   
    foreach ($key1->airports as $key=>$value) {
        echo $key;
        echo $my_value;             
            if ($key==$my_value) {
                $city = json_decode($key1->airports,true);
                // echo $key1->airlines['U2']->city;
                $city = $city->city;
                echo $city;
                return $city;
            }
    }
}
```

How can i get the city name based on the airport IATA? (iata is the three letter code key that airports objects have).

Comment: You don't need to use `json_decode`, it's already decoded. You should only need `$value->city`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$airport_code = 'ORY';

// $my_irpost_string is your json string
$data = json_decode($my_json_string, true);
$city = $data['airports'][$airport_code]['city'];

print($city);
```

You don't need foreach, as you already know the code. This means that your foreach + comparison is just array value @ code.

This is a well known antipattern: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/348682/what-is-the-for-case-antipattern

Comment: Much better than looping over the entire collection :)